# Dotted Border Box

Tags: html, css

I have dotted bordered box which is looking proper in chrome but not looking proper in firefox.

```
.circle {
    border: 1em dotted #235ea4;
    border-radius: 7em;
    height: 7em;
    margin: 2em auto 0;
    padding: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 7em;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pm8j4gno/)

Please help to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Bhumi Shah the problem are you trying to solve is can not achieve just using CSS. If you are fine to use `SVG` then `SVG` could be the solution. using SVG you can create a rounded circle with dotted border. Have a look at the [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yarolepore/1/edit) made by using SVG.

```html
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="border:1px solid #000;">
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" 
stroke="#448800" stroke-dasharray="20,10" stroke-width="20"
fill="none" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Is a open bug of mozilla firefox 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721

Comment: Yeah i've checked it but can we do it anyother way?

Comment: Is bad solution but i think is only :( Using background image

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Firefox, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721 - It was opened in 2007 but hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: Yeah i've checked it but can we do it anyother way? canvas or something else